# Rails & Active Record: How do I access a sibling association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My Movie model has_many :trailers. Trailers has a boolean column for is_feature_trailer.

In my trailers_controller index, I'm rendering all trailers.where(is_feature_trailer: false).

In _trailer.html.erb I want to show the associated feature trailer if it exists ( if trailer.movie.trailer.where(is_feature_trailer: true)  ). But I want to avoid making this query as I'm rendering each trailer.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: A movie can have many `featured_trailers` or one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify ***conditions*** on `associations`.

```
#movie.rb
has_many :trailers
has_one :featured_trailer, -> { where(is_featured_trailer: true) }, class_name: "Trailer"
```

***OR***

You can use a `scope`

```
#trailer.rb
scope :featured_trailer, ->(movie) { where(movie_id: movie.id, is_featured_trailer: true) }
```